# SQL between 2 dates not returning correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the query below and I would like to get the rows where "[Last Update Date]" is in either 2015 or 2016.

```
SELECT [NPI]
      ,[Entity Type Code]
      ,[Replacement NPI]
      ,[Employer Identification Number (EIN)]
      ,[Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)]
      ,[Provider Last Name (Legal Name)]
      ,[Provider First Name]
      ,[Provider Middle Name]
      ,[Provider Name Prefix Text]
      ,[Provider Name Suffix Text]
      ,[Provider Credential Text]
      ,[Provider Enumeration Date]
      ,[Last Update Date]
      ,[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1]

  FROM [Database].[dbo].[NPIInfo]
  WHERE[Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] in ('122300000X', '1223G0001X','1223P0221X','1223P0700X')
  AND ([Last Update Date] BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2016/12/31' )
  order by [Last Update Date]
```

I don't receive any results when I run the code above. But if I run it with this "AND" statement I get results:

```
AND [Last Update Date] like '%2015%' or [Last Update Date] like '%2016%'
```

This result gives me 500,000 + rows.

If I run it this way per year I get way less results:

```
AND [Last Update Date] like '%2015%'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? The last 2 And statements are giving me different results TIA

Comment: what type is `Last update Date` ? looks like is a string and maybe is a different format

Comment: Added `sql-server` syntax based on the non-standard identifiers used. If you are using a different DBMS, then please re-tag

Comment: It is a varchar(200)

Comment: try `select top 100 [Last Update Date] from [NPIInfo]` to see date format

Comment: Looks like this 01/02/2015 varchar 200

Comment: If you used a `DATE` column and ISO constants (`'YYYYMMDD'`) things would works rather more predictably. (And could use an index in a pleasant way.) Are the date strings zero-filled, i.e. `2015/10/01` rather than `2015/10/1`?

Comment: Convert the column, containing your dates, to the appropriate date type, then compare with the date constants. And remember, that `between` Jan 1 and Dec 31 will exclude the entire day of Dec 31.

Comment: The reason you are struggling here is because you have date values stuffed into a string. This is why the date and datetime datatypes exist. Also, you really should avoid spaces and other punctuation in your table and column names. It just makes more complicated and difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:  Apparently I'm wrong here.  Leaving the answer for reference as to what is *not* the problem.  However, the `CAST` code might work anyway.

First, you can't use `BETWEEN` with text data, you have to do it with a datetime or numeric format.  If `[Last update Date]` is text you'll need to convert it to datetime before you can do anything with it.  It would be best to change your actual data's format, but if you can't for some reason this may work:

```
AND (CAST([Last Update Date] as datetime) 
BETWEEN CAST('2015/01/01' as datetime) AND CAST('2016/12/31' as datetime))
```

Regarding your `like '%2015%'` statements, the wildcard condition you're using is specifically for text data; that's why it works at all.  The different row amounts are because the first `like` is looking for *both* 2015 and 2016, while the second one is looking for *only* 2015.

Comment: you can use `BETWEEEN` for  text data but the date have to be in format `YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: You absolutely can use BETWEEN with text data.

Comment: Dont use text to store dates. And don't use between for date ranges. Between us simply a lazy syntax shortcut and if used without good understanding it can lead to error in selection and calculation. Use >= and < instead.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Can you explain how BETWEEN leads to errors?

Comment: there is a myriad of references on this, try these to start https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common  and https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/11210/Beware-of-Between.html

Answer (score 3):

TRY

```
 WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, [Last Update Date] , 103) BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2016/12/31'
```

Check this page for the different formats

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: isn't `TO_DATE` Oracle syntax?

Comment: Oracle or mysql, or postgresql, but certainly not TSQL.

Comment: I ran the command but get this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @user1342164 check the link to see what format work better for your case

Comment: I think 101 or 103  should be the right one for you